# Maven freezes while perfoming scm:update on VSS

Tags: java, visual-sourcesafe, maven

Im trying to get source files from VSS using Maven.

But when I execute command

mvn -DvssDirectory="C:\Program Files\VisualSourceSafe\win32" scm:update

the log goes to

[INFO] [scm:update {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\VisualSourceSafe\win32\ss" Get $/TEST -R -I- -GWS"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\temp\test

and then nothing happens. No error, no success.

Can someone advice how to proceed with downloading sources from VSS?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `mvn` with the `-X` tag (to enable the debugging output) and see if you can figure out where it is getting stuck. Perhaps VSS is waiting for your credentials or something?

Doublecheck [the documentation for using the VSS SCM plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/vss.html) to make sure you aren't missing any properties. If you think you are finding a bug, try reporting an issue at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the double quotes are not interfering here. Maybe try to use the "short path name" instead:

```
mvn -DvssDirectory=C:\Progra~1\Visual~1\win32 scm:update
```

Or use the provider configuration file `$user.home/.scm/vss-settings.xml`:

```
<vss-settings>
  <Settings>
    <vssDirectory>C:\Program Files\VisualSourceSafe\win32</vssDirectory>
  <Settings>
</vss-settings>
```

And try again.